# How to kill process with node js

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

Im running BDD tests that uses IE, chrome and firefox drivers. Sometimes when my tests fails it doesnt kills the drivers so it keeps running. I want to kill all the process with the process name, something like this in windows

```
taskkill /F /IM chromedriver.exe /T
```

but with node js or something that will work along in linux and windows machines. If its with some gulp plugin would be great so I can add it as a task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for something like [fkill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fkill)

> Works on macOS, Linux, Windows.

usage examples :

```
const fkill = require('fkill');

fkill(1337).then(() => {
    console.log('Killed process');
});

fkill('Safari');

fkill([1337, 'Safari']);
```