# Node JS - Cannot Kill Process Executed with Child Process Exec

Tags: node.js, child-process

We are trying to kill the process of a chrome browser launched with nodes `child_process` exec command

```
var process = cp.exec(`"chrome.exe" --app="..."`, () => {}); // working great
```

But when we try

```
process.kill(); //nothing happens...
```

Does the process refer to the chrome window or something else? if not, **how can we get a hold of the newly opened chrome window process, PID, etc...?**

Any help would be great...

Note - we have tried using the chrome_launcher NPM but it didn't help because we couldn't open chrome in kiosk mode without fullscreen, but this is an issue for a different question...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try the PID hack

We can start child processes with `{detached: true}` option so those processes will not be attached to main process but they will go to a new group of processes.

Then using `process.kill(-pid)` method on main process we can kill all processes that are in the same group of a child process with the same pid group. In my case, I only have one processes in this group.

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var child = spawn('your-command', {detached: true});

process.kill(-child.pid);
```

Comment: There is a chance that your process will die and another with the same ID will be started.

Comment: Why is there a minus sign before `child.pid`?

Comment: The `-` in front of the PID instructs `process.kill` to kill the process group the PID belongs to instead of just the process the PID belongs to.

Comment: This solution does not appear to work for `exec` in Node v16.16.0.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ps-tree
This package explains why this does not work with exec

Answer (score 1):

I built a cross platform npm package that wraps up spawning and killing child processes from node, give it a try.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/subspawn

Answer (score -1):

I am not able to add comment, so I am saying it directly in the answer:

[How to kill process with node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45803129/how-to-kill-process-with-node-js)

If you check the link above you need library as follows

https://www.npmjs.com/package/fkill

Usage Example taken from stackoverflow question

```
const fkill = require('fkill');

fkill(1337).then(() => {
    console.log('Killed process');
});

fkill('Safari');

fkill([1337, 'Safari']);
```

I also found this library to check running processes

https://github.com/neekey/ps

Comment: This does not explain how to kill a process that has begun with `exec`. Does `fkill()` work with the `pid` property of a node child process?